# How to synchronize method with HazelCast between two nodes?

Tags: java, spring-boot, synchronization, nodes, hazelcast

There is `Spring Boot` project. Project works on two nodes. I have method for send message mail with scheduler. The message is sent 2 times, since two nodes are working. How can I use `HazelCast` to configure the method so that it works once, only by one, more optimal node? There is very little documentation and articles on the net. I have already added `HazelCast` to the project, and the nodes see each other.

*HazelCast.yaml*:

```java
hazelcast:
  network:
    join:
      multicast:
        enabled: true
```

*Gradle*:

```java
    implementation group: 'com.hazelcast', name: 'hazelcast-all', version: '4.2'
```

*ForExampleMyMethodForSendMail*:

```java
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 9 * * ?")
public void senMail(MailDTO mailDTO) {
   mailService.sendMail(mailDTO);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a `distributed map` that is visible with two `nodes` at the same time (this feature is provided by `HazelCast`). After that, I began to put the `key` `value` in this map according to the type of the `name` of the action and the `time` of the action. So the second node looked into the map, and if the action was already performed, it no longer performed it. So I solved the problem with duplicate messages.

I create distributed map:

```java
@Configuration
public class HazelCastConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Config hazelCastConfig() {
        return new Config();
    }

    @Bean
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance(Config hazelCastConfig) {
        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(hazelCastConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, LocalDateTime> timeMap(@Qualifier("hazelcastInstance") HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
        return hazelcastInstance.getMap("hazelcastTimeMap");
    }
}
```

And then I use AutoWired for work with map:

```java
private Map<String, LocalDateTime> timeMap;

@AutoWired
public void setTimeMap(Map<String, LocalDateTime> timeMap) {
        this.timeMap = timeMap;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Hazelcast distributed lock feature with your own code to ensure you send mail only once.
https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/cp-subsystem/fencedlock.html

Comment: Give me example, please!